# What is the use of the ownProps arg in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I see that the `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` function which are passed to the `connect` function in Redux take `ownProps` as a second argument.

```
[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function):

[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function):
```

What is the optional `[ownprops]` argument for?

I am looking for an additional example to make things clear as there is already one in [the Redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: Could you be more specific; what is unclear about the explanations of that argument in the documentation you link to?

Comment: I was just looking for an additional practical example where the argument was used.

Comment: Then could you [edit] the question to make that clear?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The react-redux docs don't say what it is, just that it exists, is called ownProps and that the arity of the function determines if it is passed - not what it is.

Comment: @deb0ch I don't know what it said 18 months ago, but right now it says *"the props passed to the connected component"*. Either way, the OP has since edited the question and received and accepted an answer.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If the `ownProps` parameter is specified, react-redux will pass the props that were passed to the component into your `connect` functions. So, if you use a connected component like this:

```js
import ConnectedComponent from './containers/ConnectedComponent'

<ConnectedComponent
  value="example"
/>
```

The `ownProps` inside your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions will be an object:

```js
{ value: 'example' }
```

And you could use this object to decide what to return from those functions.

---

For example, on a blog post component:

```js
// BlogPost.js
export default function BlogPost (props) {
  return <div>
    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    <p>{props.content}</p>
    <button onClick={props.editBlogPost}>Edit</button>
  </div>
}
```

You could return Redux action creators that do something to that specific post:

```js
// BlogPostContainer.js
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import BlogPost from './BlogPost.js'
import * as actions from './actions.js'

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>
  // Get blog post data from the store for this blog post ID.
  getBlogPostData(state, props.id)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => bindActionCreators({
  // Pass the blog post ID to the action creator automatically, so
  // the wrapped blog post component can simply call `props.editBlogPost()`:
  editBlogPost: () => actions.editBlogPost(props.id)
}, dispatch)

const BlogPostContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BlogPost)
export default BlogPostContainer
```

Now you would use this component like so:

```js
import BlogPostContainer from './BlogPostContainer.js'

<BlogPostContainer id={1} />
```

Comment: Note - defaultProps isn't included in ownProps

Comment: I don't get it. can you explain a bit about default props

Comment: @Ali - In the example in this answer, if the `BlogPost` component has default properties (using `BlogPost.defaultProps={}` or default argument values syntax), those values will *not* be part of the `ownProps` object. Only properties that were explicitly provided are available. This is because React fills in the defaults at a later stage, and the `connect()` code runs before that.

Comment: @goto-bus-stop I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

ownProps refers to the props that were passed down by the parent.
A component usually has 2 sources of input: the store and any props passed by its parent component.

So, for example:

*Parent.jsx:*

```
...
<Child prop1={someValue} />
...
```

*Child.jsx:*

```
class Child extends Component {
  props: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string,
  };
...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const prop1 = ownProps.prop1;
  const tmp = state.apiData[prop1]; // some process on the value of prop1
  return {
    prop2: tmp
  };
};
```

The difference between *mapStateToProps* and *mapDisptachToProps* is what each does with the store. The first is for READ, the latter for WRITE.

mapStateToProps connects the store values as props
mapDisptachToProps are functions that let you update the store.

Answer (score 11):

goto-bus-stop's answer is good, but one thing to remember is that, according to the author of redux, Abramov/gaearon, using ownProps in those functions makes them slower because they must rebind the action creators when the props change.

See his comment in this link:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/250