# Chaining redux connect mapStateToProps , to access props inside mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In order to access to the `props` of the component inside the `mapDispatchToProps` i chained my connect like so

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent));
```

And then i manage to access to the props inside the mapDispatchToProps like so

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps) => {

    const myProp = ownProps.theProp

}
```

Is it a bad things to do ? 
Any alternative exists ?

Comment: you just want to combine multiple `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: I added a precision, indeed I want to access the props in the mapStateToProps, by doing this it works perfectly , but i wonder myself if this is a good thing to do and of course if any other way exists

Comment: im having a difficult time understanding why this is necessary, is it because your selector in `mapDispatchToProps` requires existing props as arguments?

Comment: I think i found some clues here : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/250

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a bad things to do?

IMO, It is certainly bad. `connect()` is an HOC. `connect(...)(connect(...)(MyComponent))` is redundant.

> Any alternative exists ?

Use [`mergeProps`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md#mergeprops-stateprops-dispatchprops-ownprops--object) instead or break the components properly and use `redux-saga` to use a common interaction point (the redux store).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to connect mapDispatch to props and mapStateToProps is like this:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MetaDataTaggingApp);
```

Also I don't think you should have to access props in mapDispatchToProps.
mapDispatchToProps is basically just telling your component which dispatch actions it's allowed to use.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  aReduxAction,
  anotherReduxAction
}
```

If you need to pass props into these dispatches, it should be when you are invoking them.

Comment: You absolutely do have access to ownProps in mapDispatchToProps, it's right in the documentation https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#arguments

Comment: Ah I guess I've just never had to use ownProps. I've always made mapDispatchToProps an object.

Comment: Sending props at invocation is usually still better, but I'm not really sure if that's why the question asker wanted them? This is probably right though. The action they're dispatching should just take an argument

Comment: I have an empty object ownProps returned in my console by doing this :
` const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps) => {

    console.log(ownProps)`

Comment: Maybe this will help OP:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198842/what-is-the-use-of-the-ownprops-arg-in-mapstatetoprops-and-mapdispatchtoprops

Comment: I found some answers here too : https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/250